# How to put text underneath a navbar-brand in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Assuming I have a bootstrap 3 navbar with a navbar-brand containing text, how can I add a small subtitle that fits right underneath that navbar-brand?

Comment: Would you mind adding some code? http://bootply.com/new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is one way of doing it:**

#### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AFiNehIz/1/edit

---

**HTML**

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name<small>Tagline goes here</small></a>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand small {
  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
}

.navbar-toggle {top:10px}

@media (min-width:768px) {
  
  .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:20px;
  }
  
  .nav.navbar-nav a {
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

@cab's solution works, but here's another option that will not impact the height of the default navbar (due to increased padding):

```
.navbar-brand {
  line-height:12px;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}

.navbar-brand small {
  display:block;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

http://bootply.com/106312

Comment: Keep _.navbar-brand_ with default configs and apply _.navbar-brand small_ style worked to me.