# Adding a subtitle to a Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I have a Bootstrap 4 website with a navbar. The navbar has a `brand` part with an image and title text, and then there's the rest of the navbar. You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/zmbq/aq9Laaew/218793/

Now, I want to add a subtitle, under the title "A Digital Onomasticon". The problem is - the substitle is long, and I want it to extend below the nav links.

I tried everything I could think of and couldn't figure out how to do that.

NOTE: the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155060/how-to-put-text-underneath-a-navbar-brand-in-bootstrap) is not sufficient, as it yields something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zmbq/7et2uz0w/

Comment: Is the subtitle hidden when the navbar is collapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the brand and links in a separate flexbox (`d-flex`) div...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-sm flex-nowrap align-items-start">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://onomasticon.researchsoftwarehosting.org/assets/images/seal-impression.png">
    </a>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="d-sm-flex d-block flex-nowrap">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A Digital Onomasticon</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarOnavbarNavptions" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item one</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item two</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item three</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <small>A lot more text that goes under the links and should be cleverly placed, and isn't</small>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/9SK8ItOyzw

---

Related: [Bootstrap 4 navbar with 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635126/bootstrap-4-navbar-with-2-rows/42635243#42635243)

Comment: Any idea on how to combine this with right-aligning (some) nav items? When I added flex for the overall layout, my <li class="nav-item dropdown-item-right"> stopped  being right aligned (within the nav bar)...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the subtitle to position absolute to remove it from the normal content flow. It's unclear how it should look on mobile, I simply hide it in the media query. Example:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="http://onomasticon.researchsoftwarehosting.org/assets/images/seal-impression.png">
  A Digital Onomasticon
  <small>A lot more text that goes under the links and should be cleverly placed, and isn't</small>
</a>
```

---

```
.navbar-brand small {
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  white-space: normal;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .navbar-brand small {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg1pL5nt/)